# How can we print list views

Tags: administration

I have enabled "Enable Printable List Views" on the Setup -> User Interface
[image]

But i cant still see the print option on the list views. Is there anything else that need to be enabled? Cant see the option on both lightning and classic interface.
[image]

Comment: Just for confirmation, this is not a custom page? Because I can see it in my org.

Comment: Nope it isn't.  I can't see it in my org

Comment: As the name filter options are also not coming. Are you able to view it in other objects?

Comment: My bad.. it was a VF page part of an appexchange app which earlier admin had used to display the activities as a tab

Comment: You can post it as answer then :)

Comment: Unfortunately, we cant have activities as a tab. Thats the reason they had installed an app to do it. I guess the answer provided by Mahmood should work with all other list views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=basics_faq_which_records_print_listviews.htm&type=5)

> 1. Navigate to the list view.
> 2. Click the print icon at the top of the
>      page. A printable page view displays.
> 3. To print the page, click Print
>      This Page.

Goto the list view and then you will see a printer icon (screenshot below)

**SF Classic experience**

[image]

Comment: In my case, i was looking at listviews for activities which could not be added as a tab. So earlier admin had installed an app which uses a VF page  to show the activities as a tab. Enabling the print option in setup -> userinterface doesnt make a difference to the VF page. Your answer is perfect for all other objects. I will accept this as answer even though it doesnt work in my case as its a VF page

Comment: Ok. Well you don't have to if that doesn't solve your issue. Since, VF page part was not included in the question hence I responded with that. If the VF page is custom then you can use `renderAs="pdf"` and if its managed package then you're pretty much out of options. :-)

Comment: i still went ahead accepting it as an answer as it would help other people who would be coming to this thread :)